# Error in login with twitter function on React Native app

Tags: ios, react-native, authentication, twitter, twitter-login

I am trying to include login with twitter functionality in React native ios app. I configured the twitter app in twitter developer portal with these settings
[app settings in twitter developer portal app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xz9Lg.png)
[app settings in twitter developer portal app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tLyVq.png)
[app settings in twitter developer portal app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NtP4v.png)

and then enter the code consumer key and secret in the code

About the code,
i am using https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-login-twitter this package

i completed all the steps

and made a function as below,

```
twitterSignIn: async () => {
      RNTwitterSignIn.init(
        config.TWITTER_COMSUMER_KEY,
        config.TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET,
      );
      RNTwitterSignIn.logIn()
        .then(async (loginData) => {
          console.log('loginData...', loginData);
          await twitterLogin({
            access_token_key: loginData.authToken,
            access_token_secret: loginData.authTokenSecret,
          }).then(async (response) => {
            console.log(response);
            if (response.success) {
              await AsyncStorage.setItem('userId', response.id);
              await AsyncStorage.setItem('userToken', response.tokens.access);
              await AsyncStorage.setItem(
                'userTokenRefresh',
                response.tokens.refresh,
              );
              dispatch({
                type: 'LOGIN',
                id: response.id,
                token: response.tokens.access,
                refreshToken: response.tokens.refresh,
                firstLogin: response.first_login,
              });
            } else {
              Alert.alert(
                'Something went wrong. Make sure an email is attached with your facebook account',
              );
            }
          });
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
          alert('Unable to Login with Twitter');
        });
    },
```

but i am getting error as below

```
Error: Twitter signin error
    at Object.promiseMethodWrapper [as logIn] (NativeModules.js:103:51)
    at twitterSignIn$ (AuthActions.js:228:20)
    at tryCatch (regeneratorRuntime.js:44:17)
    at Generator.<anonymous> (regeneratorRuntime.js:125:22)
    at Generator.next (regeneratorRuntime.js:69:21)
    at tryCatch (regeneratorRuntime.js:44:17)
    at invoke (regeneratorRuntime.js:75:20)
    at regeneratorRuntime.js:96:13
    at tryCallTwo (core.js:45:5)
    at doResolve (core.js:200:13)
```

-Regenerated the consumer keys and secret
-Re-installed the package and pod